# Why side menu view coming from down?, how to make it left side menu?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, side-menu

I am using left side menu from [this pod](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) using storyboard. sidemenu is working fine in Swift 4.2 version pod. but I have updated pod in Swift 5 here I am not getting this menu in attribute inspector to give left side menu on,

[image]

in Swift 5 `pod 'SideMenu', '~> 6.0'` I am getting full menu from below, I am not getting left side menu.

**that's why I am trying to add this code in appDelegate:**

```
 let leftMenuNavigationController = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController)
 SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = leftMenuNavigationController
```

but here what should I write in `YourViewController` place

in console I am getting like below:

> Failed to set (leftSide) user defined inspected property on (UINavigationController): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key leftSide.

This is small demo project you can find pod installing and error here [github project](https://github.com/SwiftSamples/sideMenuDemo)

I need side menu like this.. I use to get like this in Swift 4 pod

[image]

How do I add left side menu in updated version?

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

I just checked your project. The segue that you have created is of kind "Present Modally", just change it to "Push"

Present Modally is like presenting a popup and so its default animation is bottom to top.

Push has a default animation of right to left.

[image]

Also, you are not using the latest pod version. Update you pod.

[image]

And then I removed the class name from SideMenuNavigationController and assigned it again. Wait for Xcode to suggest the name by itself then press enter.

[image]

**Final Result**

[image]

Comment: Have you got left side menu?? as you mentioned i changed button segue to `kind Show (e.g. push)` but same getting from below only why?? did u changed anything else in code?? please help

Comment: yes like your out put i am also getting, but i want side menu on the background view like i have updated question with screen shot in pod swift4. how do i achieve like above.. here background view also moving

Comment: please try to fix this issue.. i will upvote and i do accept for sure :)

Comment: For that you will have to make changes in SideMenuPresentationStyle. Play with the code. I can't do your entire homework for you, just help you with it :)

Comment: Okay no problem, I did upvote for your time spent on my code, but i cant accept because if i give `present modally` segue also working fine, thank you!!!